# How to check if a string is all lowercase/uppercase using TypeScript type system? (not runtime check)

Tags: typescript

Now that TypeScript includes [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) how would one assert if a string is all uppercase or lowercase?

Comment: What do you mean by "assert" in this case? A [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)?

Comment: Yes,  a type assertion, i.e. whatever the equivalent of `type TestLowercase<S extends string> = S === Lowercase<S>;` would be, where `===` is pseudo-code.

Comment: Please include a [mre] of what kind of behavior you're expecting.  Is `"foo123"` all lowercase?  How do you expect such a type assertion to work?  There is not currently a specific type in TypeScript representing such strings, but you can use generics to represent a constraint that will do it. Do you have a function that should only accept "all uppercase" or "all lowercase" strings?  Some concrete example code is helpful to focus the question.

Comment: I have a function that should accept only all uppercase strings.

Comment: Is TypeScript including template literal types relevant to the question being asked in the title?

Comment: Note that in ASCII/English this might be easier, but in other languages the notion of "case" gets quite fluid, where there might be more than one "uppercase" glyphs for a single "lowercase" glyph, for example

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wol7jw) work for your needs?  There are a slew of caveats.  If the approach works for you I can write up an answer; otherwise please specify the failing use cases and I'll see if they can be addressed (but there are lots of things we can't do anything about)

Comment: TypeScript already has helpers for intrinsic string manipulation, such as [`Uppercase<S>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype). The question is effectively if there is a way to assert if `S === Uppercase<S>`.

Comment: You should probably edit the title to specify that you want TypeScript's *type system* to represent something like "a type corresponding to all-uppercase strings" otherwise you're going to get all these runtime answers

Answer (score 0):

`T` fallback to never so when unspecified you can get a nag. Then conditionally return never to make the return nag if parameter is not the uppercase of the generic argument.

```js
const upperLog = <T extends string>(str: `${Uppercase<T>}`): `${Uppercase<T>}` => {
  return str as `${Uppercase<T>}`;
};


upperLog("c"); // will error but "C" is accepted
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without requiring the end-user to also specify the generic parameter as well?